# Merge two text files at a specific location, sed or awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have two text files, I want to place a text in the middle of another, I did some research and found information about adding single strings:

I have a comment in the second text file called STUFFGOESHERE, so I tried:

```
sed '/^STUFFGOESHERE/a file1.txt' file2.txt
```

sed: 1: "/^STUFFGOESHERE/a long.txt": command a expects \ followed by text

So I tried something different, trying to place the contents of the text based on a given line, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sed '/STUFFGOESHERE/ r file1.txt' file2.txt
```

If you want to remove the STUFFGOESHERE line:

```
sed -e '/STUFFGOESHERE/ r file1.txt' -e '/STUFFGOESHERE/d' file2.txt
```

If you want to modify file2 in place:

```
sed -i -e...
```

(or maybe `sed -i '' -e...`, I'm using GNU sed 4.1.5.)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use ex or ed, try

```
cat <<EOF | ex -e - file2.txt
/^STUFFGOESHERE/
.r file1.txt
w
q
EOF
```

The same script works for ed:

```
cat <<EOF | ed file2.txt
/^STUFFGOESHERE/
.r file1.txt
w
q
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/STUFFGOESHERE/{while((getline line<"file1")>0){ print line};next}1' file2
```

Answer (score 1):

From a Unix shell (bash, csh, zsh, whatever):

```
: | perl -e '@c = join("", map {<>} 0..eof); print $c[0] =~ /STUFFGOESHERE/ ? $` . $c[1] . $'"'"' : $c[0]' file2.txt file1.txt > newfile2.txt
```

Comment: For some reason which I can't see why the text file is either put in after the other file, and not after STUFFGOESHERE

Comment: Your sentence is malformed, but I'll guess what you mean.  The main reason is that I write all of my scripts to take their input either from standard input or from files named as arguments. I never hardcode them into the script.  This is a matter of fundamental scripting hygiene.  Another reason is that Perl doesn't have a function that takes a filename and returns the file's contents, like PHP does.